# Run Background Task with SQLite DB using Windows RunTime Component with

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I need to create a background task for my application's secondary tiles.

The task should update on every day midnight.

I am retrieving the data from db and doing some calculations.

So I've added Windows Runtime Component to my Component project to my solution.

But the problem is, I can't access the methods of my parent class or its objects in Windows Runtime Component class.

Is it possible to access parent project/class from Windows Runtime Component?

and I also need to bind to XML from SQlite db.

Help me. Thank You

Comment: Put your class in a class library and add it as a reference.

Comment: OKay. But what to do in main project, if we put classes in a class library?

Comment: Reference the library from there too.

Comment: @Karan have you got solution?But my project is in UWP